# Set viewport at the end of the JTree on inserting a new node

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, viewport, jtree

I have a JTree which is in a JScrollPane. I would like to update the viewport and set it to the end of the JTree upon inserting a new node.

I want to do something similar to this...

```
   scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane ));
   scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

   DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textPane.getCaret();
   caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

but with JTree not JTextPane. The JTree class does not have a `getCaret()` method, so
I have checked the JTree API but could not find what I need. 
Is there an easy way to get this working?

Comment: See things like [`JTree.getPathBounds(TreePath)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getPathBounds-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-) & [`JComponent.scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible-java.awt.Rectangle-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [`JViewport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) of the scroll pane, and use [`JViewPort#scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle contentRect)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29). Something like

```
int y = tree.getPreferredSize().height;
pane.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, y, 0, 0));
```

Here's a full example

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class TestViewPort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(Integer.toString(i)));
                }
                JTree tree = new JTree(root);
                tree.setVisibleRowCount(10);
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
                pane.setViewportView(tree);
                int y = tree.getPreferredSize().height;
                pane.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, y, 0, 0));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane);
            }  
        });
    }
}
```

---

- Or simply as AndrewThompson pointed out `tree.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, y, 0, 0));`, as `JTree` also has this method.

---

### UPDATE: probably best solution

- Or another solution (maybe better) [`tree.scrollRowToVisible(tree.getRowCount() - 1);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#scrollRowToVisible-int-)